# Better way of assigning a php function to a variable session within the same page before redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, redirect

On the handler page i need something along the lines of this to work:

```
    $mobile = preg_replace('/^07/','447',$phonenumber);
```

this will assign the outcome of the preg_replace to the var $mobile, and if the phonenumber entered is not a mobile number it will not assign the variable, However if it is assigned i need to then assign it to a session before redirecting the user automatically, The handler page has (2) outcomes..

1)  The handler redirects to a page where no SMS message information is neccessery as the user did not enter a Mobile number however they entered a Landline.

2)  The user gets sent to the sms related page.

`$_SESSION['mobauth'] = $mobile`;    <---  Need to create a session or a way to have the page redirect with the $mobile variable information stored else where to be called on the related page.

The redirection will follow the lines of:

```
 if(isset($_SESSION["mobauth"])){
   header('Location: mobile-sms.php');
  exit; 
 }
```

Comment: Can`t you just do simple POST form when the user types phone number, then do some simple if(){}else{} validation to choose where to redirect him?

Comment: fsn, i thought of that but its quite a bit of messing about as the site is basically completed, i thought if i add this function to the handler its not effecting the site in anyway.  Adding extra fields means changing CSS files and much more. as its an 6 step form (6 pages included) - I know jrad has commented below i dont know if thats worth a try... going to test it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add hidden form input fields into the handler and have a javascript function do the redirect in the way of submitting the form form you.

So the user will be redirected to the form action address being called instantly from the javascript and that way on the next page you can have `$mobile = $_POST['mobauth'];`  or better still you can assign the POST to a session like so:

```
       if(isset($_POST['mobauth']))
       $_SESSION['mobauth']=$_POST['mobauth'];
```

And here is the javascript form redirect script:

```
<form id="YourFormID" method="POST" action="nextpage.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="mobauth" value="<?php echo $mobile; ?>"/>
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById("YourFormID").submit();
</script>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

First of all before using session you have to start the session at top of the page as :

session_start();

And you you will check the assign some paramter in session as :

$_SESSION["mobauth"] = "mobile";

After that on other page you can user it. Also start session on other page also.

Comment: The problem is i need to assign the value returned from the $mobile variable otherwise it will not run exactly how it should do on the next page.. I could just assign a value like you have done above but come to processing on next page it will try to send a sms message to that value instead of a number and causes errors

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the session at the top of the file by 
session_start(); 
after initialization you will redirected to the the page you have given in the header function!

Comment: asim, i already have session start visible i should have mentioned that, i have just updated my question. i have commented below to SolutionsWithUS if you want to read what i said to him that maybe able to give you a better idea.